# flex, network analyst, closest facility

Tags: arcgis-server, network-analyst, arcgis-flex-api

I am trying to build a network analyst in flex, with the closest facility.

A problem has occurred during the process of solving closest route to find the incident. 
In ArcGIS for Desktop, there is no problem about the distance between incident and facility, and the route can be solved easily.

However, when I publish in ArcGIS for Server and I set as the input data in flex, the distance is limit.  The closest route is only solved when the distance between incident and facility less than 1 meters.

Is there any parameter that I may have missed when I published the service, or is there an alternative procedure to manage the maximum distance of the closest route?

Comment: Could it be that you have not specified the Cutoff value properly? This is done when preparing the network analysis layer in ArcMap before publishing a map service with Network Analysis capability on.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this esri sample server about the limit setting:
http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/NetworkAnalysis/SanDiego/NAServer/ClosestFacility

Also this is a good online sample resource for your specific issue:
https://developers.arcgis.com/en/flex/sample-code/closest-facility.htm